# How to filter certain type of exceptions in logback

Tags: logback

I used some exceptions to handle some validation logic. The thing is that spring boot (1.5) with logback logs all exceptions by default.

Can you help me with the  properties to add in the  in logback.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Add filter with expression in your logback xml. Below you will find logback xml. Apart from this you have to add janino dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- logback -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.16</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

logback.xml

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="test" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>

    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>return  (message.contains("javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException"));
            </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>

    </filter>

</appender>



<logger name="com.logbacke.example"
    level="ERROR" additivity="false">

    <appender-ref ref="test" />
</logger>

<!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```